# addSPLookupFieldXML within JSON template

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, json, choice-field, site-design

Ok I am running into issues for creating a choice field within a document library.

I cannot get the addSPLookupFieldXML to work properly within the JSON template.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Been using these links to try and figure it out:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/field-element-field

```
{
    "verb": "createSPList",
    "listName": "Test List",
    "templateType": 101,
    "subactions": [
      {
        "verb": "setDescription",
        "description": "Teat List Library"
      },
      {
        "verb": "addSPLookupFieldXml",
        "schemaXml": "Field Type"\"Choice"
        "isRequired": false,
        "addToDefaultView": true
      }   
    ]
  },
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Adding a choice column or lookup column to list?

Comment: I am trying to add a choice column within a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to add a choice column to your list then you need to pass the choices to field. Check below example:

```
{
  "verb": "addSPFieldXml",
  "schemaXml": "<Field ID=\"{596cbd92-36e3-40cc-a910-0f53468ce5e4}\" Type=\"Choice\" DisplayName=\"Project Category\" Required=\"FALSE\" Format=\"Dropdown\" StaticName=\"ProjectCategory\" Name=\"ProjectCategory\"><Default>Operations</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Operations</CHOICE><CHOICE>IT</CHOICE><CHOICE>Legal</CHOICE><CHOICE>Engineering</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>"
}
```

**Documentation**: [Site design JSON schema - addSPFieldXml](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/site-design-json-schema#addSPFieldXml)

**Update from Comments**:

If you are using it across multiple site collections and multiple document libraries then I will recommend you to create this choice field as **Site Column**. Below is the example code the creating a site column, adding to a content type and adding it to document library:

```
{
    "$schema": "schema.json",
    "actions": [
        {
            "verb": "createSiteColumn",
            "fieldType": "User",
            "internalName": "PolicyOwner",
            "displayName": "Policy Owner",
            "isRequired": false,
            "group": "DevFacto IS Custom Columns",
            "enforceUnique": false
        },
        {
            "verb": "createSiteColumnXml",
            "schemaXml": "<Field Type=\"Choice\" DisplayName=\"Policy Type\" Required=\"FALSE\" Format=\"Dropdown\" StaticName=\"PolicyType\" Name=\"PolicyType\"><Default></Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Policy</CHOICE><CHOICE>Procedure</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>"
        },
        {
            "verb": "createSiteColumn",
            "fieldType": "DateTime",
            "internalName": "PolicyExpiryDate",
            "displayName": "Policy Expiry Date",
            "isRequired": false,
            "group": "DevFacto IS Custom Columns"
        },
        {
            "verb": "createContentType",
            "name": "Policy",
            "description": "Policy Document",
            "parentName": "Document",
            "hidden": false,
            "subactions": [
                {
                    "verb": "addSiteColumn",
                    "internalName": "PolicyOwner"
                },
                {
                    "verb": "addSiteColumn",
                    "internalName": "PolicyType"
                },
                {
                    "verb": "addSiteColumn",
                    "internalName": "PolicyExpiryDate"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "verb": "createSPList",
            "listName": "Documents",
            "templateType": 101,
            "subactions": [
                {
                    "verb": "addContentType",
                    "name": "Policy"
                },
                {
                    "verb": "addSPView",
                    "name": "By Policies",
                    "viewFields": [
                        "Name",
                        "PolicyOwner",
                        "PolicyType",
                        "PolicyExpiryDate",
                        "Modified",
                        "Editor",
                        "Version"
                    ],
                    "query": "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name=\"Name\" Ascending=\"FALSE\" /></OrderBy><GroupBy Collapse =\"TRUE\"><FieldRef Name =\"PolicyType\"/></GroupBy><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ContentType\"/><Value Type=\"Computed\">Policy</Value></Eq></Where>",
                    "rowLimit": 100,
                    "isPaged": true,
                    "makeDefault": false
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "bindata": {},
    "version": 1
}
```

You can read more about it at:

1. [Getting Started with SharePoint Site Designs and Site Scripts](https://www.devfacto.com/blog/sharepoint-site-designs-site-scripts/)

Comment: I have tried this, does not work. I am looking to see how it is placed within the JSON file. Is it a sub action within createSPList? Also I am not trying to place it on a specific list, this is a template that is used for multiple site collections with the same library. Having a specific field ID will not work.

Comment: Check updated answer and let me know your thoughts.

Comment: And yes, it is a sub-action which you can use within `createSPList` verb.

Comment: Both answers did work, but are not exactly what I am looking for. I have a document library called "test library" that will be created for each "test site collection" I create with the JSON template. Each "test library" will have its own unique ID so I cannot use a specific ID for the library. Please let me know if this doesn't make sense, I'll try to do a small visio drawing.

Comment: First of all we are not passing any ID for the library and second, You will not face any issues if you are creating a document library in different site collections & they are having same ID.

Comment: """"schemaXml": "<Field ID=\"{596cbd92-36e3-40cc-a910-0f53468ce5e4}""" this is what I am talking about

Comment: That is a GUID for a choice field. This will not cause any issue as you are creating this column in different site collections each time this script runs. So, it should work fine for you.

Comment: If I create a content type within the script will it go to the content type hub for the tenant?

Comment: No, the content type will not go to the content type hub automatically from site design. It will only create a content type at site collection level. If you want you can create a content type in one of the site collection, publish it to the content type hub and then reuse it in your site design script.

Comment: Now the last question is how do you get it in the default view? I tried the "addToDefaultView" and it did not show when the script was ran

Comment: As per the documentation you need to set `addToDefaultView` property to `true` and it should work for you. Also, Please [Upvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109492/discussion-between-hittle08-and-ganesh-sanap).

Comment: Still cant get it into the default view using addToDefaultView: true, I have tried it in the subactions of the library and in the content type

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$site_script = '
    {
        "$schema": "schema.json",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "verb": "createSPList",
                    "listName": "testLib",
                    "templateType": 101,
                    "subactions": [
                        {
                            "verb": "setDescription",
                            "description": "testlib"
                        },
                        {
                            "verb": "addSPField",
                            "fieldType": "Text",
                            "displayName": "Name",
                            "isRequired": false,
                            "addToDefaultView": true
                        },
                {
  "verb": "addSPFieldXml",
  "schemaXml": "<Field ID=\"{596cbd92-36e3-40cc-a910-0f53468ce5e4}\" Type=\"Choice\" DisplayName=\"Project Category\" Required=\"FALSE\" Format=\"Dropdown\" StaticName=\"ProjectCategory\" Name=\"ProjectCategory\"><Default>Operations</Default><CHOICES><CHOICE>Operations</CHOICE><CHOICE>IT</CHOICE><CHOICE>Legal</CHOICE><CHOICE>Engineering</CHOICE></CHOICES></Field>"
},                  
                    ]
                }
            ],
                "bindata": { },
        "version": 1
    } '
```

Test result:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I may be thinking about this is the wrong way but the field ID will make that column specific to that document library correct?